# Unable to move the cache: Access is denied and Unable to create cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

when I run streamlit show this

> C:\Users...\src>streamlit run streamlit.py

```
C:\Users\...\src>
[4772:0604/211416.186:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)]  Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
[4772:0604/211416.186:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(205)] Unable to create cache
```

I really don’t know why this is happening! But I ran the example in the tutorial earlier, which had @st.cache_data in it, and I ran it several times, and then the system crashed, and then I ran it again and it showed the above. I deleted streamlit and installed it again. I tried to replace it with a different version, but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file from **streamlit.py** to **streamlit_app.py**.